# Google Sheet COVID-19 automatically updating table

Tags: java, json, google-sheets, graph, datatables

I don't know all that much about coding or anything similar. I need help with creating a  google sheet that automatically updates using data from [this source.](https://coronavirus.maryland.gov/datasets/master-casetracker-2/geoservice?orderBy=FID&orderByAsc=false&selectedAttribute=MONT&where=ReportDate%20%3E%3D%20TIMESTAMP%20%272020-04-23%2000%3A00%3A00%27%20AND%20ReportDate%20%3C%3D%20TIMESTAMP%20%272020-05-31%2023%3A59%3A59%27)

I managed to get the data onto my spreadsheet by using =ImportJSON("") but it looked very messy. From what I could tell, the way I did it made it so that new data gets recorded on a new rows of the spreadsheet.

What I'm trying to do is to extract only the most recent numbers and sort in separate tables so that I could create bar graphs but I don't know how to do that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcCFP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would need some sort of an interface supported by Google Sheets that can automatically update values from an external source. An example would be Microsoft Excel's RTD (real time data). It works much like any other Excel function (Average, Sum, etc), but connects to an external data source. RTD specifically pulls live stock prices from sources like TDAmeritrade or Bloomberg finance. I don't know of an interface that supports that COVID site specifically.

You said you aren't that familiar with coding, but if you're willing to learn a bit more, you make your own rudimentary program that pulls whatever data you want from that website. Then you can manipulate, graph, or display it as you wish. The former is known as web scraping. JSoup is an opensource Java library that you can download as a .jar file and reference within a java program so as to seamlessly extract data from an html source. Check out https://jsoup.org/ and https://stackabuse.com/web-scraping-the-java-way/ if you're interested in this method. It will take a bit of extra learning, but it'll give you the most flexibility in rapid data acquisition and manipulation. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) script for this. It's a really easy language to learn very similar to JavaScript with the ease of making operations for Google tools using objects like [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) which you can use to get or set values in the sheets' cells. You can import the JSON object using [URLFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and use the data as you wish to set the values you need in the sheets. In case your request is a simple "GET" request, there's an example below to get the JSON object. In case it's a "POST" request you can check the examples in the documentation I linked.

```
function setValuesFromJSON(){
    var url = [URL-TO-FETCH];
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) is a guide on how to get information from a JSON object.